# Magnetic field line experiment in space

Tags: magnetic-fields, space

I was wondering what would happen if you take a bar magnet (maybe in a long cylindrical form so that there are no edges) to space, let it float and carefully and slowly sprinkle iron filings around it.

How would the result look like? Would I get a 3-dimensional representation of the magnetic field lines? Or just a big mess?

I couldn't really find any answer to this question on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnetic forces involved are stronger than the gravitational forces on iron particles, so it will be much like on Earth. In the lecture room, I show my students this demo: http://chinalabsupplies.com/magnetic_demo/1257-1.jpg

We also have iron filings in a gel. The poster came up with this nice video, where one sees how the iron particles in oil get attracted also to each other and orient themselves - this gives the impression of field lines. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKyFHDJL_1s